# How can I give windows permission to one of my EXT3 partitions in ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, ext3

I have an ext3 partition I would like to share with windows.  I have the ext2fsd driver for windows, which works great.  I can view all of my ubuntu files from windows.  The only problem is that I don't have write access to this partition.  Is there any way I can give all permissions to everything so that I can write from windows?  I don't really mind giving up security on the partition, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is to find the folder you need, and mark it 'anyone can read/write'
So run 'chmod -R 0776 /path/to/folder' in terminal to free up permissions

While I do not suggest it, Doing a quick 'chmod -R 0777 /' should unlock every file on the partition...
But this might mess up some things and cause programs to go "WHOA THERE" *I'm looking at you SSHD*